# modal-dialog or div overlay over frameset?

Tags: html, modal-dialog, frameset

I have a html page with several frames in it (also nested framesets). I want to show an overlay over all these frames to show a modal box / light box. Is that possible?

I know, i know, framesets are not good to use, but I want to give it a try!

[a modal dialog example](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.htm)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately completely impossible.

The only `HTML Element` that will overlay over a `frameset frame`.. is the drop down list portion of a `Select` list.

In a similar situation, I built the same "frameset" using `iframe`s.  It was the only way to overlay over the frames.

Comment: do you mean that you nested a frameset in an iframe in your case?

Comment: I rebuilt the frameset/frames using iframes.  e.g. the page that originally defined a `frameset` with `frames` it now only contains `iframes`.  I had to ditch the `frameset` entirely.